# MS Access : Dealing with today's date in calculated field expression

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hi I am creating a table in MS Access to store the details of children in a school.

I have a field called YearGroup which needs to calculate the school year they are in based on their date of birth and whether they have been moved up or down a year.

I.e. if the expression deems they are six years old they should be placed in year 2. If they were moved down or up a year they should be in year 1 or 3 (this is based on another field in the table called YearModifier).

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
Year(Now()) - IIf(Month([DOB]) > 8, Year([DOB]) + 6 + [YearModifier], Year([DOB]) + 5 + [YearModifier])
```

My problem is that `Year(Now())` is returning as invalid expression. Lots of websites have recognised using the Now() function and also I've tried Date() but nothing seems to be accepted by Access (The version is 2010).

What is going on? How can I get today's date in a calculated field expression?

Thanks

Comment: Oh and the IIf is about whether their birthday comes before or after September, the cutoff point for the next school year.

Comment: Which property in the field do you have this expression in? Default Value?

Comment: There is no Default Value for this Data Type for some reason. This is in the property "Expression"

Comment: To make this a little simpler, the real problem lies in this error:

The expression Year(Now()) cannot be used in a calculated column.

Comment: You could try calculating it in a query instead. A little research suggests that Date functions can't be used in calculated columns (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1c0fbd37-8dff-4552-b550-29aa0dde3972/the-expression-cannot-be-used-in-a-calculated-column?forum=accessdev for example).

Comment: Ok, not the end of the world, thanks. Is there a way in Access I can make a function of my own accessible from all queries called? It's just that i'm going to have to use this calculation many many times.

Comment: Yes. Just create a Public Function and let it return the year of the current date

Comment: Something like (eventually):
     SELECT * FROM "Child" WHERE CalcGroup(DOB)=1

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a query with all of the fields from your table, and then add an extra field `YearGroup: Year(Now()) - IIf(Month([DOB]) > 8, Year([DOB]) + 6 + [YearModifier], Year([DOB]) + 5 + [YearModifier])`

It appears that Date functions can't be used in calculated columns in tables.

Comment: Date functions can be used in queries as any other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the year, which might work in field expressions:

format(date(),"yyyy")

About your function (which I have re-written very slightly)

```
Year( Now() ) 
- Year([DOB])
- IIf(  Month([DOB]) > 8
      , 6 
      , 5 )
+ [YearModifier]
```

however!

I don't think you want to use now().  Which year they are in depend on their age at the 1st Sept at the start of the current academic year not now!  Ok now will work until 31/dec/2015, so I must assume you will not be using the function after this date!

If you are you must use 2015 not Now().

Ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the age of the children with a simple function:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Then your expression would be something like this (ignoring the modifier):

ClassYear: IIf(AgeSimple([DOB]) > 6, 2, 1)

Comment: Being new to Access/VBA development, I am not exactly sure where this code is placed. I added a Module and made a function that returns True or False based on which I want to set a calculated field (Yes/No). The Expression Builder does not show my new function listed under functions, and rejects the expression on typing manually as well. Could you please point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just copy-paste the above into the module, compile and save.

Comment: I get the following error when I hit save in Access:
"The Expression Iif(isActiveDuty([EndDate]), True, False) cannot be used in a calculated column."

Comment: That may be right. I never use calculated columns, they are just a (too) "smart" feature aimed at superusers. Leave the table as is with clean columns/fields and create a _query_ for the purpose.