# Difference between two columns, choice of columns varies when more data is added

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table in access:

```
ID Week
1   Wk1
1   Wk2
3   Wk2
3   Wk3
```

I constructed a query, spreading the table across weeks. The crosstable looks like this:

```
ID  Wk1  Wk2  Wk3
1   1     1    0
3   0     1    1
```

I want to create a column that gets the difference  between the last two columns. Something like this:

```
ID  Wk1  Wk2  Wk3  Diff
1   1     1    0   -1
3   0     1    1    0
```

This column should be variable. That is, as I get more data on more weeks (e.g. Wk4, Wk5, and so on) the variable column should reflect the difference between the last two weeks. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: read about **calculated fields** in ms access. for example http://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-table-calculated-field-compute-quarter-date

Comment: I tried that. For a numeric value it would be max(Week) - ( max(week) - 1 ). However, this field is not numeric and does not take the max function.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358560/ms-access-dealing-with-todays-date-in-calculated-field-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open for VBA solution then below is how i achive a workaround to your desired output.
In basic it operates on table with columns and query to do the desired calculation field.

The concept is to build a query sql everytime you run a function or a sub - it's up to you.

So it firstly build up a query getting every field, than at the end it adds CALC fiels that is substracting values, of last and second to last, fields of table.

```
Public Function func3(table_or_query As String)

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim Ccount As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim name_last As String
Dim name_last_min_1 As String
Dim quera As QueryDef
Set quera = db.QueryDefs("kw_test_stack1") ' - name of query to be replaced


strSql1 = "SELECT "

Ccount = db.TableDefs(table_or_query).Fields.Count '- for tables 
'Ccount = db.QueryDefs("YourQueryName").Fields.Count - for queries

For i = 1 To Ccount - 1 ' - here you start building a new sql for each of fields in desired table
name = db.TableDefs(table_or_query).Fields(i).name
name = table_or_query & "." & name
strSql1 = strSql1 & name & ", "
Next i

name_last = db.TableDefs(table_or_query).Fields(Ccount - 1).name ' - here you get names of last and second to last columns
name_last = table_or_query & "." & name_last
name_last_min_1 = db.TableDefs(table_or_query).Fields(Ccount - 2).name
name_last_min_1 = table_or_query & "." & name_last_min_1

strSql1 = strSql1 & name_last & " - " & name_last_min_1 & " as Calc FROM " & table_or_query &";" ' - finishing building of a query
quera.SQL = strSql1 ' - update of the query

func3 = name_last & " , " & pos1 & " , " & strSql1  ' - ommit i used it for a testing purpose

End Function
```